# Deplhi: Filtering loaded HTML by chromium enbedded (CEF VCL)

Tags: delphi, interface, filter, chromium, chromium-embedded

I`m trying to create some prototype of browser (using CEF VCL for Deplhi – chromiumembedded), that filters loaded content before translating it to DOM.

I decided to handle onResourceResponse event (right?) – it has the argument *filter*. I don`t need to add something to existing data or cut, just replace some chars of just transferred HTML-code.

There`s my handling of onResourceResponse:

```
procedure TForm1.Chromium1ResourceResponse(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const url: ustring;
  const response: ICefResponse; var filter: ICefBase);
begin
if (url = 'http://some.path.to/file.html')
  begin
  // filter := some object using interface ICefBase here maybe?
  end;
end;
```

Here`s a declaration of ICefBase:

```
ICefBase = interface
  ['{1F9A7B44-DCDC-4477-9180-3ADD44BDEB7B}']
  function Wrap: Pointer;
end;
```

But i can`t understand how to use it.

Thanks for help! Sorry for my broken English :) I hope I explained the problem properly.

Using Delphi 7.

UPD:

This code works:

```
type
  TContentFilter = class(TCefContentFilterOwn)
  public
    procedure ProcessData(const Data: Pointer; Size: Integer;
        var SubstituteData: ICefStreamReader); override;
  end;
// --------
procedure TContentFilter.ProcessData(const Data: Pointer; Size: Integer;
        var SubstituteData: ICefStreamReader);
var c: PAnsiChar;
    i: integer;
begin
c := Data;

for i := 0 to Size-1 do
  begin
  if (c[i] = '<') or (c[i] = '>') then
        c[i] := ' ';
  end;

end;
// --------
procedure TForm1.Chromium1ResourceResponse(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const url: ustring;
  const response: ICefResponse; var filter: ICefBase);
var f: TContentFilter;
begin
if (response.GetHeader('X-RemoveLTGT') <> '') then
  filter := TContentFilter.Create();
end;
```

Comment: You can return your descendant of `TCefContentFilterOwn` in which you implement `ProcessData` method. There you can set SubstituteData to an instance of `TCefStreamReaderRef` which will be loaded instead of the received data.
However, from my quick experiment, the `OnResourceResponse` event is not called for the main (HTML) response, only for additional resources referenced from it (javascript, images, etc.). So to filter the HTML content itself you'll probably need another event or figure out how to configure chromium to call this event for main response.

Comment: Correction, the `OnResourceResponse` event handler was called, but for some reason the filter's `ProcessData` callback was not called. Maybe I missed something, try it for yourself...

Comment: TOndrej, thanks for `TCefContentFilterOwn` – I need this one. It works now.

Furthermore, ProcessData callback was called propertly. Maybe, old version?

Comment: @TOndrej, can you give some links to read more about chromiumenbedded? Where you had found info about `TCefStreamReaderRef`?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was only UTSL... Using The Source, Luke! :-)

Comment: Yes, maybe I used an older version. Does it work for you? Should I post the comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes it works. Please, repost that comment as answer, then i`ll check it as Right.

You can add the code below as example of using TCefContentFilterOwn (maybe it can help someone :)

Comment: I`ve tried to pos code here, but I can`t format it normally, so i will answer, but your answer will marked as right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return your descendant of `TCefContentFilterOwn` in which you implement `ProcessData` method. There you can set `SubstituteData` to an instance of `TCefStreamReaderRef` which will be loaded by the browser instead of the received data.